# Why does Firefox name its UI interface configuration file : userChrome.css?

Tags: firefox, browser, userchrome.css

Why does Firefox name its UI interface configuration file : **userChrome.css** ? why not **userFirefox.css** ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The word "chrome" refers to the "skin" or basically what the UI looks like. The Google browser called Chrome came along later.

Answer (score 6):

User interface features are sometimes referred to as "[chrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface)". [Google Chrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome) was called Chrome because it's a nicer skin with webkit rendering. Hope that helps :)